# サーバー移行後にPHPで Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ',' or ';' とエラー表示される

Tags: php

webサイトのコンテンツをサーバー移行して（失敗して）元に戻した時にこのように出てきて、開けない状態です。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ',' or ';' in
 /var/www/public_html/wp-content/plugins/yyi-rinker/yyi_rinker_main.php
 on line 20
```

yyi_rinker_main.phpの20行目は

```
const EXPIRED_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

なのですが、何がいけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo {
    const TWO = ONE * 2;
}
```

のように[オブジェクト定数で式を利用できるのはPHP5.6以降](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.constants.php)です。

質問のようなエラーがでるのであれば実行しているPHPのバージョンが古くなっている可能性があるので5.6以上に上げてください。

なお、WordPressで現在サポートされているのは[5.6.20以降](https://ja.wordpress.org/2019/04/03/minimum-php-version-update/)([推奨は7.3以上](https://ja.wordpress.org/about/requirements/))となっています。

Comment: php7にしたところ、かいぜんしました！ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

こんばんは。

推測ですが、
サーバ移行により、以前とPHPのバージョンが変わっているためだと思います。

PHP5.5以前は、
const（定数）に、「24 * 60 * 60」といった式を入れることができませんでした。

以前のサーバと、現在ご利用中のサーバのPHPバージョンをご確認ください。
もし私の推測が正しければ、後者のPHPバージョンを5.6以上にアップすることをオススメ致します。

参考
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: php7にしたところ、かいぜんしました！ありがとうございます